# Custom event not getting triggered for standard table in SAP

Tags: event-handling, abap, sap-erp, custom-events

I need to have a custom event on a standard table. The event should get triggered whenever there is any new entry added to standard table or changes made in table. Also inside that custom event I need to insert some custom code.

NOTE: Not sure if we can add custom logic in case of standard event for the standard table. My case I need to check for custom events for standard table. Kindly also suggest if custom event for standard is recommended in case there are no standard event.

Standard table: `AGR_USERS`

**My Inputs**

I have created one custom event by creating sub object of  standard event `BUS2032` (sales order). I have written custom logic to update a custom table inside custom created event on change (to update custom table). When I am creating sales order no entry is inserted in custom table.

Steps I followed:

1. Transaction code `SWO1`: created custom subtype of `BUS2032`.
2. Tcode: created custom event for custom created subtype of `BUS2032` in step 1.
3. Tcode `SWEC`: created new entry for events of change document with custom subtype and event, also selected create radio button.
4. `SE24`: created one custom class in which in event inserting entry in custom table.
5. `SWE2`: added details as shown in image.

Now when I create Sales order using `VA01`, no entry is inserted in custom table.

Kindly suggest

Comment: I don't get why you are requesting an "event" to execute your own code. Why do you need to create an event in a Business Object type in `SWO1`? Also, `BUS2032` is not an event. You didn't tell which event you are talking about. Also, there is no general logic in SAP ERP about "standard tables", each case has its own specific solution. Your case is about executing ABAP code in some unknown scenario when you run `VA01`, it's all what I understood.

Comment: My requirement is To capture real time addition/changes in standard table(AGR_USERS) and send to btp workflow.